# Visualize iteratively t-SNE in Dash for large sample dataset

Tags: python, dataset, visualization, plotly-dash

I'm building a Dash app. In this dashboard, there is the possibility for the user to perform a dimension reduction of the dataset and visualize the result on a 2d or 3d plot.

The computation is really slow as the dataset contains lots of samples (~ 30000) and the algorithm (T-SNE) is not the fastest one.

I would like to allow the user to visualize the result of the algorithm performed on a small subset (between 1000 and 3000 samples) of the dataset then perform the algorithm on the full dataset and show the final result when it is computed (https://opentsne.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/04_large_data_sets/04_large_data_sets.html).

This way the user shouldn't have to wait 10min or more to see results.

In code, the idea would be the following

```py
@callback(
    Output(id=ids.TSNE_GRAPH, "figure"),
    Input(id=ids.START_ALGO, "n_clicks"),
    Input(id=ids.DATASTORE, "data")
)
def start_algo(n_clicks: int | None, data: pd.DataFrame):
    if n_clicks is None:
        raise no_update

    data_subset, data_rest = split_data(data)
    res = fast_computation_tsne(data_subset)
    fig = px.scatter(res[:,0], res[:,1])
   
    # show the fig in UI

    full_res = slow_computation_tsne(data_rest)
    full_fig = px.scatter(res[:,0], res[:,1])
    
    # show the full fig in UI
```

The problem is that as I understand we can only return one time something to the output.

Comment: One way to achieve this is to use a [background callback](https://dash.plotly.com/background-callbacks). Starting from the example 5 in the documentation, you could define a 2-step progress, the 1st step would be to create the light figure using a separate function, ie. something with `progress_default=fast_tsne_figure()` in the @callback decorator, and in the function body then you keep only the code responsible for building the full figure (step 2). I think it's not an issue to have the main output being the same as the `progress` output, that is,  `Output(id=ids.TSNE_GRAPH, "figure")`.

Comment: Rethinking about that, you won't be able to pass any callback argument to `fast_tsne_figure()` when set as `progress_default`, so if you need the light figure to be created from the input store data, you will need to add a step, ie. set `progress_default=go.Figure()` (step 1), and in the function body call `set_progress(fast_tsne_figure(data_subset))` (step 2), before the code that returns the full figure (step3).